# Blade templating variable reference

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.6

I have a list of items which I want to render in the following way:

```
@foreach($campaignList as $campaign)
<div class="col-md-{{12/$columns}}">
    @include('admin.includes.campaign_card',['campaign'=>$campaign,'link'=>true])
</div>
@endforeach
```

The `admin.includes.campaign_card` template (with [debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pr6vW.jpg))

```
@extends('admin.includes.base_campaign_card')
{{$campaign}} // Here the data is okay
@section('options')
    {{$campaign}} //Here however I get the first item on each loop
@endsection
```

Basically the `campaign` object within the section remains the same when looping.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue is related to the fact that you can have just one section with a given name at a time.

There is way to force blade to rerender with `@overwrite` directive (which is not in the docs apparently) instead of `@endsection`.

[Github comment](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/15666#issuecomment-250444585)